# Ajax - how can I get data using changing hidden input element values

Tags: jquery, input, get, onchange, hidden

> ```
> <form name="reservation" id="reservation" class="reservation" action="validate_form.php"  method="post">
> <input type="hidden" name="side_check_in_date" id="side_check_in_date" value=""/>
> <input type="hidden" name="side_check_out_date" id="side_check_out_date" value=""/>
> <select name="side_room_type" id="room_type" onchange="return getAdultRoom(this.value)" class="input-medium"><?=room_type_cmb();?></select>
> ```

```
<script>
var xmlHTTP;
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    xmlHTTP=null;
    try
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");            
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }

}
function getAdultRoom(room_id)
{
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
         else
          {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

          if(xmlhttp == null)
          {
              alert("Your browser not support the AJAX");   
              return;
          }

          var url = "ajax_fetch_room.php?room_id="+room_id;
          //xmlhttp.onreadystatechang = handleResponce();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
           if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
             document.getElementById("roomadult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
          } 
          xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
          xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>
```

Hi! 
I have one one selectbox. When room is selected it gets data from ajax_fetch_room.php
This script above is working but I also added 2 hidden inputs to form as a check-in and check-out date. When check-in and check-out dates are selected from a calendar, hidden inputs are changing. I want to get data from ajax_fetch_rooms.php as it belows

> ajax_fetch_room.php?room_id="+room_id+"&side_check_in_date="+side_check_in_date+"&side_check_out_date="+side_check_out_date;

How should I edit it to make it work?

P.S. I don't mine to use jquery as long as it works. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value using jQuery:
    `$('#yourHiddenFieldId').val();`

So it should be something like:

```
room_id="+room_id+"&side_check_in_date="+$('#side_check_in_date').val()+"&side_check_out_date="+$('#side_check_out_date').val();
```

Without using it should by something like:

```
document.getElementById('yourId').value
```

So it will translate to:

```
room_id="+room_id+"&side_check_in_date="+document.getElementById('side_check_in_date').value+"&side_check_out_date="+document.getElementById('side_check_out_date').value;
```

Comment: Hi! can you show fully using of this? I am not very good at ajax/jquery

Comment: Off topic, but I would suggest you take a look at $.ajax (jQuery) that's a lot easier than 'xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");'. And if you have some time, search youtube for some AngularJS tutorials

Comment: Thank you very much Nick! It worked. I have been trying this to work since 3 hours. I can't believe that it was so easy. The final query is like this : room_id="+$element('#room_type').val()+"&side_check_in_date="+$element('#side_check_in_date').val()+"&side_check_out_date="+$element('#side_check_out_date').val();